# AllocatePages return EFI_NOT_FOUND for memory type as EfiMemoryMappedIO?

Tags: c, memory, bios, uefi

Hi I'm trying to allocate **EfiMemoryMappedIO** pages to be able to access this memory from Windows driver later. Every time I am trying several boot memory regions.

Below is list of memory regions, which I test

```
#define EFI_BOOT_MEMORY_REGIONS_LOW 0x90000, 0x88000, 0x80000
#define EFI_BOOT_MEMORY_REGIONS_HIGH \
0x100000, 0x200000, 0x300000, 0x400000, 0x500000, 0x600000, 0x700000, 0x800000, \
0x900000, 0xA00000, 0xB00000, 0xC00000, 0xD00000, 0xE00000, 0xF00000, 0x1000000

#define EFI_BOOT_MEMORY_REGIONS EFI_BOOT_MEMORY_REGIONS_LOW, EFI_BOOT_MEMORY_REGIONS_HIGH
```

I list all of the addressed above and try to **AllocatePages()** for every address, until it succeeds for one of them in the following way:

```
static EFI_STATUS
PrepareMemory(
       IN UINTN    Address,
       IN UINTN    Len,
       OUT VOID**  ppMemory)
{
    EFI_PHYSICAL_ADDRESS PhysAddr;
    UINTN Pages = 0;
    VOID* pAllocatedMemory = NULL;
    EFI_STATUS Status = EFI_SUCCESS;
    PhysAddr = Address & ~0x0fff; // set alignment to page size (for x86, x86-64 page size if 0x1000)
    Pages = ((Len & ~0x0fff) + 0x1000) >> 12;
    Status = BS->AllocatePages(AllocateAddress, EfiMemoryMappedIO, Pages, &PhysAddr);
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
        LOG_ERROR_FN(L"!!! ERROR: Failed to prepare memory 0x%x (status = %d)", (UINTN)PhysAddr, Status);
        DbgEfiPrint((L"!!! ERROR: Failed to prepare memory 0x%x (status = %d)\n", (UINTN)PhysAddr, Status));
        DbgEfiPressAnyKey();
        return Status;
    }
    pAllocatedMemory = (void*)(UINTN)PhysAddr;
    SetMem(pAllocatedMemory, Pages << 12, 0);
    *ppMemory = pAllocatedMemory;
    return Status;
}
EFI_STATUS
copy_into_boot_memory_region()
{
    LOG_INFO_FN(L"enter");
    UINTN BootMemoryRegions[] = { EFI_BOOT_MEMORY_REGIONS };
    UINTN BootMemoryRegionIndex = 0;
    UINT8* pMemoryRegion = NULL;
    EFI_STATUS Status = EFI_NOT_FOUND;
    for (BootMemoryRegionIndex = 0; BootMemoryRegionIndex < sizeof(BootMemoryRegions) / sizeof(BootMemoryRegions[1]);
         ++BootMemoryRegionIndex)
    {
        Status = PrepareMemory(BootMemoryRegions[BootMemoryRegionIndex], 1024, (void**)&pMemoryRegion);
        if (!EFI_ERROR(Status))
        {
            LOG_ERROR_FN(L"Copy into boot memory region: 0x%x", (UINTN)pMemoryRegion);
            DbgEfiPrint((L"Copy into boot memory region: 0x%x\n", (UINTN)pMemoryRegion));
            DbgEfiPressAnyKey();
            gBS->CopyMem(pMemoryRegion, (UINT8*) ADDRESS, 1024);
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            LOG_ERROR_FN(L"PrepareMemory() for boot memory region [%lu] failed with status = 0x%llX!", BootMemoryRegions[BootMemoryRegionIndex], Status);
        }
    }
    if (EFI_ERROR(Status))
    {
        LOG_ERROR_FN(L"Failed to copy into boot memory region, status = 0x%llX!", Status);
    }
    LOG_INFO_FN(L"leave");
    return Status;
}
```

This logic is used from **VeraCryptLib** [enter link description here](https://github.com/DavidXanatos/DiskCryptor/blob/40c949a50e67a30f28813f89ee6ef2ef8dbdc101/DcsPkg/Library/VeraCryptLib/DcsVeraCryptImpl.c)
But recently I have found a case, when system fails to **AllocatePages()** for every of regions, that are listed above with error = **EFI_NOT_FOUND**.

Does anybody knows possible reasons of such behavior?

Maybe I can just make list of regions bigger adding here some more addresses? In such case which addresses also can be used to allocate **EfiMemoryMappedIO** pages?? I couldn't find any documentation about boot memory regions address range

*Or maybe there are some other ways to send data from UEFI to OS through memory?*

Comment: From the UEFI spec: "Note:
UEFI Applications, UEFI Drivers, and UEFI OS Loaders must not allocate memory of types EfiReservedMemoryType and EfiMemoryMappedIO."

Comment: @prl Are there any other ways to send data from UEFI to OS through memory?

Comment: It's no problem to allocate memory and put data there for the OS to read. (Allocate the memory as Runtime Data, so it persists.) The only difficulty is communicating to the OS where to find the data. Here's a few ways I can think of off the top of my head: an EFI variable; an entry in an ACPI table; some unused field of the BDA or EBDA. The first one is probably the least hacky of these. (In fact, if the data isn't too large, you can just put the whole contents into the variable.)